# I have query on inline fuction

Tags: c, function, inline

When inline function gets executed, which memory area they will use

Let me give some example
int sum(int a,int b)
{return a+b;
}
Where the variables a and b are stored ?

Comment: Techically, they are "automatic" storage class (stored on the stack), but since their addresses are never taken, by the AS_IF rule, they might be stored in registers or completely eliminated by the optimizer and not stored anywhere.

Comment: @Chriss Dodd For Inline function there does not involve any overhead of pushing the variables on stack then how does it is possible ?

Comment: Variables don't have to be stored anywhere. Under the as-if rule, an implementation is free to optimise them out completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely no memory is used at all. If the arguments of `sum()` are in registers at the time of the "call", then they will simply be added and the sum put in another register, or one of those registers if the contents are not needed after that.

For example, this:

```c
inline int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    (void)argv;
    int a = argc;
    int b = a * 5;
    return sum(a, b);
}
```

Compiles to this:

```
_main:                                  ; @main
    .cfi_startproc
; %bb.0:
    add w8, w0, w0, lsl #1
    lsl w0, w8, #1
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

All done in the registers. Nothing stored in memory. (And the optimizer added instead of multiplied.)